# AntLR4: Write grammar for Dockefile

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr4, dockerfile

I'm trying to write a grammar that can recognise *dockerfile*. (context-free grammar)
Long story short, dockerfiles are text files composed of commands.
A command can be single or multi-lines and identified by its name.

Simplest examples of dockerfile command:

`FROM anImageNameThatCanContainsPrettyMuchAnythingButWS`

`EXPOSE aNumber`

There are a bit more complicated commands such as:

`ADD aPath anotherPath`

`COPY aPath anotherPath`

`ENV aKey=aValue`

And here are the most complicated command the `RUN` command.
A `RUN`command can basically be any *shell* command, so can be anything. The only thing I try to achieve is to 'split' `RUN`commands by `&&`.

What I have done so far:

```
grammar Dockerfile;

dockerfile: ((COMMENT | command))+ EOF;

COMMENT
    :   ( '#' ~[\r\n]* '\r'? '\n'
        | '/*' .*? '*/'
        ) -> skip
    ;

command: one_line | run;
one_line: (from | env | entrypoint | maintainer | workdir | add | copy | expose) (NEWLINE)*;

from: FROM ANYKEYS;
maintainer: MAINTAINER ANYKEYS ANYKEYS;

env: ENV ANYKEYS '=' ANYKEYS;

entrypoint: ENTRYPOINT ANYKEYS;

workdir: WORKDIR ANYKEYS;

add: ADD .*?;

copy: COPY src dest;
src: ANYKEYS | '.';
dest: ANYKEYS | '.';

expose: EXPOSE NUMBER;

run: RUN body NEWLINE;
body: shellCmd (SHELLAND shellCmd)* ;
shellCmd: ANYKEYS+;

SHARP: '#';
FROM: [fF][rR][oO][mM];
ENV: [eE][nN][vV];
RUN: [rR][uU][nN];
ENTRYPOINT: [eE][nN][tT][rR][yY][pP][oO][iI][nN][tT];
MAINTAINER: [mM][aA][iI][nN][tT][aA][iI][nN][eE][rR];
WORKDIR: [wW][oO][rR][kK][dD][iI][rR];
SHELLAND: '&&' | ('\\' NEWLINE '&&');
ADD: [aA][dD][dD];
COPY: [cC][oO][pP][yY];
EXPOSE: [eE][xX][pP][oO][sS][eE];

NUMBER: [0-9]+;
LETTER: [a-zA-Z];
ANYKEYS: (LETTER | NUMBER | ':' | '_' | '-' | '/' | '|' | '"' | '=' | '*' | '\\' | '\'' | '+' | ']' | '[' | '{' | '}' | ';' | '!' | '~' | '.' | '–' | '$' | '<' | '>' | '@' | ',')+;

NEWLINE: ('\n' | '\r')+;
WS : ((' ' | '\t')+) -> skip;
```

So what is wrong?
First of all the `ANYKEYS` rule is ulgy but I can find how to do this in a better way..
Next, `RUN exit 9000` won't work, yielding `extraneous input '9000' expecting {SHELLAND, ANYKEYS, NEWLINE}` error that I don't understand since `ANYKEYS` should match `NUMBER` in the `ANYKEY` rule

I am a bit lost, don't understand why it does not match such input, and don't know how to do this in a better way

Thanks for your help and advices !

Comment: You fell into the [lexer trap](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/antlr/3271/lexer-rules-in-v4/11235/priority-rules#t=201611261634280733531). You probably should use lexer modes anyway in case the command happens to have an argument that matches one of your keywords.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer ! But moving `ANYKEYS` as the end of the grammar wont change anything am I wrong? So I dont get what can I do right know to fix this? Using mode will fix this?
If I understand lexer mode correctly, is can be used to introduce kind of context in the grammar, avoiding ambiguious case like `RUN` being iterpreted as RUN commands whereas it is inside a RUN body.

Comment: Antlr4 will try to match the possible longest token first.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I read docs and example about mode but I dont see, in my case, how can i pop from the Run mode, there is not token to leave run mode. You leave run mode when, after new line; you read one the other commands

Comment: Hmmm yes the default lexer may not be well suited for this kind of task. Are you sure ANTLR is not overkill for this? I guess a hand-written parser for this should be really easy to write, the grammar is simple enough.

Comment: To be honest I was looking for a standard way to parse dockerfile and give it back to the community. Moreover, I still dont know how to write the regex for the RUN command if it what you had in mind :)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski, you were right. This language has no depth, no parentheses and therefore can be handled by regular expressions (what I have done). Of course it can be handled by AntLR grammar but, as you said, it is a bit overkill.. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with AntLR4, but it will be important for your grammar to include the multiple forms of some of the instructions.

The following instructions have two forms:

```
RUN
ADD
COPY
ENTRYPOINT
HEALTHCHECK
```

The following instruction has three forms:

```
CMD
```

---

#### RUN

The `RUN` instruction has two forms:

```
RUN <command>                          # (shell form, the command is run in a shell
                                       #  which by default is /bin/sh -c on Linux
                                       #  or cmd /S /C on Windows)

RUN ["executable", "param1", "param2"] # (exec form)
```

---

#### ADD

The `ADD` instruction has two forms:

```
ADD <src>... <dest>
ADD ["<src>",... "<dest>"] # (this form is required for paths containing whitespace)
```

---

#### COPY

The `COPY` instruction has two forms:

```
COPY <src>... <dest>
COPY ["<src>",... "<dest>"] # (this form is required for paths containing whitespace)
```

---

#### ENTRYPOINT

The `ENTRYPOINT` instruction has two forms:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["executable", "param1", "param2"] # (exec form, preferred)
ENTRYPOINT command param1 param2              # (shell form)
```

---

#### HEALTHCHECK

The `HEALTHCHECK` instruction has two forms:

```
HEALTHCHECK [OPTIONS] CMD command # (check container health by running a command inside the container)
HEALTHCHECK NONE                  # (disable any healthcheck inherited from the base image)
```

---

#### CMD

The `CMD` instruction has three forms:

```
CMD ["executable","param1","param2"] # (exec form, this is the preferred form)
CMD ["param1","param2"]              # (as default parameters to ENTRYPOINT)
CMD command param1 param2            # (shell form)
```

---

For more information and examples of each command see: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/